# Scala, abstract logic over very similar types

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I have the feeling that I can abstract my code further but I am a little stuck. I am doing this more as a challenge, so don't worry about premature optimisation. It's for my open source library [Reactive Kraken](https://github.com/ticofab/reactive-kraken).

If you look at this code, I'm sure you'll get what I mean.

```
case class Response[T](error: List[String], result: Option[Map[String, T]])
case class OrderResponse[T](error: List[String], result: Option[T])

def handleRequest[T: JsonFormat](request: HttpRequest): Future[Response[T]] =
  fireRequest(request)
    .map(_.parseJson.convertTo[Response[T]])
    .recover { case t: Throwable => Response[T](List(t.getMessage), None) }

def handleOrderRequest[A: JsonFormat](request: HttpRequest): Future[OrderResponse[A]] =
  fireRequest(request)
    .map(_.parseJson.convertTo[OrderResponse[A]])
    .recover { case t: Throwable => OrderResponse[A](List(t.getMessage), None) }
```

The difference between these two functions is simply the type that they return. How would you go about this? Maybe using higher 
kinded types?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to unify `Response` and `OrderResponse`:

```
case class Response[T]     (error: List[String], result: Option[Map[String, T]])
case class OrderResponse[T](error: List[String], result: Option[T])
// ===
type Response[T] = OrderResponse[Map[String, T]]
case class OrderResponse[T](error: List[String], result: Option[T])
```

and then the function on `OrderResponse` is also one on `Response`. However, I don't know about the semantics of these types.

If that's not satisfactory, a typeclass will do:

```
trait Recovering[T] {
  def recover(error: Throwable): T
}
object Recovering {
  def apply[T: Recovering] = implicitly[Recovering[T]]
}

implicit def requestsAreRecovering[T]: Recovering[Request[T]] = new Recovering[Request[T]] {
  override def recover(error: Throwable) = Request[T](List(t.getMessage), None)
}
implicit def orderRequestsAreRecovering[T]: Recovering[OrderRequest[T]] = new Recovering[OrderRequest[T]] {
  override def recover(error: Throwable) = OrderRequest[T](List(t.getMessage), None)
}

def handleRequest[T: JsonFormat: Recovering](request: HttpRequest): Future[T] =
  fireRequest(request)
    .map(_.parseJson.convertTo[T])
    .recover(Recovering[T].recover)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without abstracting, you can still factorize your code :

```
case class Response[T](error: List[String], result: Option[Map[String, T]])

case class OrderResponse[T](error: List[String], result: Option[T])

private def handle[T: JsonFormat, U](request: HttpRequest, recovery: Throwable => U): Future[U] = {
  fireRequest(request)
    .map(_.parseJson.convertTo[U])
    .recover { case t: Throwable => recovery(t) }
}

def handleRequest[T: JsonFormat](request: HttpRequest): Future[Response[T]] =
    handle(request, {t: Throwable => Response[T](List(t.getMessage), None)})

def handleOrderRequest[T: JsonFormat](request: HttpRequest): Future[Response[T]] =
    handle(request, {t: Throwable => OrderResponse[A](List(t.getMessage), None)})
```